# Is it possible to create email alias for receiving payment throught the PayPal API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'd like to programmatically add email alias on my PayPal account and I was wondering if this was possible (I can't find any documentation on it!).

If this is not possible, could it be possible to allow the whole domain instead? (like sending a payment to xyz@mydomain.com would work, and zyx@mydomain.com too)?